# Typesafe Activator on Heroku Error Binding to PORT

Tags: java, heroku, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I just updated our old Play 2.1 app to the new Typesafe Activator with Play 2.3.8. I noticed that the app now appears to have an activator launcher in the root of the project. I'm trying to deploy the app on Heroku and get this error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

My Procfile looks like:

```
web: ./activator "-Dhttp.port=${PORT} ${JAVA_OPTS} -Dconfig.file=${CONFIG_RESOURCE}" run
```

The app is very very small and I'm nearly certain there should be any reason it would take longer than 60 seconds to boot and bind to the port. Locally it binds immediately with that exact same command.

Any ideas what could cause the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend *not* using `activator` to run your app in production.

Heroku runs the `sbt stage` command against your application, which creates a `target/universal/stage/bin/<app-name>` script that can be used to launch your app.  This is a better way of running in production because it eliminates any overhead or potential quirks do to activator and/or sbt.

Your `Procfile` should probably look like this:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/<app-name> -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dconfig.file=${CONFIG_RESOURCE}
```

Of course, replace `<app-name>` with the name of your app in `build.sbt`. the `JAVA_OPTS` will be picked up automatically.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like the entire structure of the Play framework changes every couple of months, and when running locally I did not see the binary in target/ like I did before. Was not aware that Heroku ran the sbt stage command :)